# Firebase user idToken not getting refreshed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an app and using firebase to manage users. I'm successfully creating a user and then successfully logging him in.

The problem comes when I request the idToken.
I have tried

```
FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
mUser.getToken(true)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
            // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
            // ...
        } else {
            // Handle error -> task.getException();
        }
    }
});
```

I have also tried

```
final FirebaseAuth.IdTokenListener handle = new FirebaseAuth.IdTokenListener() {
        @Override
        public void onIdTokenChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser mUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(mUser!=null){
                Log.w("User getToken: user :", mUser.getDisplayName());
                mUser.getIdToken(true)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                                    Log.w("User getToken: ", idToken);

                                } else {

                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    };

    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.addIdTokenListener(handle);
```

when

```
Log.w("User getToken: user :", mUser.getDisplayName());
```

gets called the info I'm getting is from the newly created user but when

```
Log.w("User getToken: ", idToken);
```

gets called, the token value is always the same. Weird thing is it was working before today. I haven't made any changes, so I am at a loss as to why the token I'm receiving is always the same even though the current user is changing.